# I am trying to call a json file but it is not working

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am expecting to see john printed out from this json file appended to my HTML because of `results.innerHTML = data.user;`. I am using a web hosting server to open the file so nothing locally there.

However I am getting printed out `hello world`  , so the `document.write` is being processed but not the call for ajax function. Why is that happening ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("hello world")
    function ajax_get_json(){
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("GET", myList.json, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                var results = document.getElementById("results");
                results.innerHTML = data.user;
            }

        }
        hr.send(null); 
        request.innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> ajax_get_json();</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is
    myList.json file

:

```
    {
      "user": "John", "age":22, "country":"United States"
    }
```

Comment: What data you are getting in response ?
Could you find any error in console ?

Comment: This error would be quite easy to track down if you just kept your eye on the console. On the line `hr.open("GET", myList.json, true);` you would see an error something like "Cannot find property json of undefined", or "myList is not defined". That would have alerted you that you were passing a variable instead of a string as you should. Without learning how to look at the console, you're going to have a very hard time debugging your programs. After all, you can't post a question to SO every time you make a mistake like that. Stop what you're doing and learn how to use the console.

Comment: @torazaburo that is fine I am a newbie and I have to disagree with you thinking I am posting this to find bugs. I am posting this because I thought I misunderstood the json function call. But console error lookup is something I overlook and I just learned that from this post. so in the end I did learn something. stop -1 people for no reason

Comment: Hi @MohamadZein. Glad you learned something. I rarely downvote, but I do when the OP has not exercised rudimentary common sense in using widely available tools to debug before posting.

Comment: @torazaburo 3 other people upvoted and disagreed with you. each have his opinion. you could say the same thing about every other post and ask them why they did not use their "common sense". common sense to you is sometimes not to others. thank you for your advice

Comment: Using the console is common sense for everyone. So is reading the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
hr.open("GET", "myList.json", true);
```

The `hr.open` second parameter should be an string which contains the URL of file

Comment: Cannot really agree with scavenging for green check marks by finding typos in people's code. Conceptual (not actual) -1.